# GoogleCloud DataFlow Failed to write a file to temp location

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, apache-beam

I am building a beam pipeline on Google cloud dataflow.

I am getting an error that cloud dataflow does not have permissions to write to a temp directory.

[image]

This is confusing since clearly dataflow has the ability to write to the bucket, it created a staging folder.

[image]

Why would I be able to write a staging folder, but not a temp folder?

I am running from within a docker container on a compute engine. I am fully authenticated with my service account.

```
PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
BUCKET=gs://$PROJECT-testing

python tests/prediction/run.py \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project $PROJECT \
    --staging_location $BUCKET/staging \
    --temp_location $BUCKET/temp \
    --job_name $PROJECT-deepmeerkat \
    --setup_file tests/prediction/setup.py
```

EDIT

In response to @alex amato

1. Does the bucket belong to the project or is it owned by another project?
   Yes, when I go the home screen for the project, this is one of four buckets listed. I commonly upload data and interact with other google cloud services (cloud vision API) from this bucket.
2. Would you please provide the full error message.

   "(8d8bc4d7fc4a50bd): Failed to write a file to temp location 'gs://api-project-773889352370-testing/temp/api-project-773889352370-deepmeerkat.1498771638.913123'. Please make sure that the bucket for this directory exists, and that the project under which the workflow is running has the necessary permissions to write to it."

   "8d8bc4d7fc4a5f8f): Workflow failed. Causes: (8d8bc4d7fc4a526c): One or more access checks for temp location or staged files failed. Please refer to other error messages for details. For more information on security and permissions, please see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions."
3. Can you confirm that there isn't already an existing GCS object which matches the name of the GCS folder path you are trying to use?

Yes, there is no folder named temp in the bucket.

4. Could you please verify the permissions you have match the members you run as

Bucket permissions have global admin

[image]

which matches my gcloud auth

[image]

Comment: Does the bucket belong to the project or is it owned by another project? Would you please provide the full error message. Can you confirm that there isn't already an existing GCS object which matches the name of the GCS folder path you are trying to use? Could you please verify the permissions you have match the members you run as. Use the Storage section in the google cloud console UI, locate the path and click the ... icon and click edit permissions, and expand the member groups

Comment: Can you also give access to cloudservices account (<project-number>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com) as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions.

Comment: that did it, thanks, changing the cloudservices account to storage admin worked. It was already inheriting the service account credentials from the compute engine, i would have thought it would have had access. Add as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@chamikara was correct. Despite inheriting credentials from my service account, cloud dataflow needs its own credentials.

> Can you also give access to cloudservices account (`<project-number>@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) as mentioned in cloud.google.com/dataflow/security-and-permissions.

Comment: link is here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with a different cause: I had set object retention policies, which prevents manual deletions. Given that renaming triggers a deletion, this error happened.

Therefore, if anyone runs into a similar issue, investigate your temp bucket's properties and potentially lift any retention policies.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29883898)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @isopach, the question was already answered. But the same error can be triggered by another cause, which I fixed, so I added my contribution in can it can help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar errors while moving from **DirectRunner** to **DataflowRunner**:

> Staged package XXX.jar at location 'gs://YYY/staging/XXX.jar' is inaccessible.

After I've played with the permissions, this is what I did:
at `Storage Browser`, clicked on `Edit Bucket Permissions` (for the specific bucket), added the right Storage Permission for the member `ZZZ-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

I hope this will save future time for other users as well.